# Adding {} to map breaks it

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Why does this work:

```
const final = pdata.map((p) => p.nodeName);

// returns [ 'H1', 'P', 'P' ] like its supposed to
```

But this returns undefined in all of them:

```
const final = pdata.map((p) => { 
  p.nodeName
});

// returns [ undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

I need to add a couple if statements inside to check for the different types but the `{}` seems to break it. Am I not supposed to this this in a `.map()`? Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usage of `{...}` is to encapsulate multiple statements.

You need to specify the `return` keyword:

```
const final = pdata.map((p) => { 
  return p.nodeName;
});
```

Comment: Please just vote to close as a duplicate instead of answering.